# Texcount command not found system in MacTeX

Tags: pdftex, mactex, shell-escape, texcount

I have a problem trying to invoke `texcount` from LaTeX file. I am using MacOS with MacTeX 2018 installed. `texcount` comes directly with the MacTeX and it is on the PATH. When I run `texcount` on command line, it works great. However, when I try to include it in the `tex` file, I get an error saying:

```
"sh: texcount: command not found system returned with code 32512".
```

I have `--enable-write18 --shell-escape` enabled and I use variety of other shell commands that work like charm on my TeX distribution. Just to verify, I have tried to execute `pstopdf` from LaTeX to see if it works and it is working great. I don't understand why only `texcount` doesn't work.

If anyone could throw me some light on what could be the possible problem, that would be great. This is the sample code I am working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\NewDocumentCommand\wordcount{s}{%
    \immediate\write18{texcount -sum -1 \jobname.tex -out=count.txt}%

}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\wordcount*
\end{document}
```

Comment: It sounds as though the PATH isn’t being passed. Try using the full path to the command: `/Library/TeX/texbin/texcount`. PS: just use `—shell-escape` the other is redundant.

Comment: Great! It works with full PATH. For example, when I checked `pstopdf`, it worked and I see `pstopdf` is at `/usr/bin/pstopdf`. Apparently, `texcount` is at different PATH. How can I make sure that LateX always looks at correct PATH?

Comment: No problem with my MacTeX.

Comment: @MahiPai : are you playing with the PATH variable in your .profile or somewhere else or is it the standard set by MacTeX? What do you get for the PATH when you run `echo $PATH` in Terminal?

Comment: @HerbSchulz, I found out the problem finally. It is with my TeX editor, TeXStudio. Apparently, I need to provide the path of tex distribution in the `TeXstudio -> Preferences -> Build -> Advanced Search Path` in `Command` option. After, I added `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin` to the command option, MacTeX commands could be used by calling from LaTeX files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already solved.